# OpenCV : Detect faces in given circular region

Tags: .net, opencv

Please note I am new to OpenCV and yet exploring.

I have to detect only those faces that are inside the Oval region ( Ref Image )[image]

If more than two faces appears, need to detect the closest one. I am using .Net Win Forms.

It will be helpful for me if any ref links.

Note : Tried googling

Comment: For the one who down voted ... Won't mind if you down vote n number of times. But at least give a reason for it ... Share your knowledge ...

Answer (score 0):

- Detect the faces using Haar classifiers.
- With the bounding box rectangle(x,y,w,h), compare whether the face points are inside or close to the oval using the [pointPolygonTest](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=pointpolygontest#pointpolygontest) function in OpenCV.